# How to get adFormResponses for multiple account id's in one call to linkedin adFormResponses API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am fetching form responses using linked API
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adFormResponses?q=accounts&account=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:1234567&projection=(paging,elements*(id,formResponse(submittedAt)))&timeRange.start=167580000&start=0&count=1000

I have multiple account id's for which I want to fetch the form responses. I dont want to do multiple calls for achieving this. I have tried adding multiple account id's in the api like
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adFormResponses?q=accounts&account=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:1234567&account=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:94537334&projection=(paging,elements*(id,formResponse(submittedAt)))&timeRange.start=3425345&start=0&count=1000

but in response I am getting only the data for the first ID 1234567 and second one is ignored.